# swift3 accepting a file from airdrop

Tags: ios, appdelegate, airdrop

I am sharing files on my app between devices using airdrop.

What is the app delegate method that is called on the receiving device when the file is received?  I have looked in the documentation and online but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Airdrop has nothing to do with your app. It's simply the OS handling documents so you have to register your app as being capable of opening that type of document.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Although to be honest, I'm not sure if this works for Airdrop as well. This works for mail though.

Comment: I have done this - ash, the link you provided has the last bit of what I need, thanks

Comment: I have been looking and am unsure how to implement the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]` such that I receive the url of the file